# jQuery in wordpress works bad in ie8

Tags: jquery, wordpress, internet-explorer-8

I want to develop simple slideshow in WordPress with jQuery.  It works nice in all browsers except IE.

```
var blockShow = function(element,nav,duration) {
  //alert(element);
  container = jQuery(element); // but in this function throw error: Object doesn't support this property or method
}

// this works
jQuery(document).ready(
  function() {
    if(jQuery('#header-slideshow')) {
      blockShow('#header-slideshow');
    }
  }
);
```

**UPDATE**: I forgot to say: outside WP it working perfectly. In IE and everywhere else, so it have to be something in WP.

Answer (score 0):

from my experience if something is not working in ie, but is everywhere else, its one of 2 things.

1 - you have some syntax slightly wrong somewhere - mayde invalid html (try validating your html and css http://validator.w3.org/) an extra comma or something. Other browsers tend to be better at ignoring minor syntax bugs

2 - you have some kind of conflict with wordpress' existing scripts. Try reorganising the load orders.

without seeing the actual site, the only other thing I can recommend is to back up your template, and systematically delete wordpress elements one by one until it works! It helps identify the problem code.